# Mongoose Group count by periods of 15 seconds

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Model which has a createdAt object and I'm needing to get the quantity of docs grouped by 15 seconds each.

What is the equivalent of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE time_stamp >= foo GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_stamp) DIV 15;` in which it returns how many docs where added in a period of 15 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example where docs are grouped from

```
  00:00 - 00:14,
  00:15 - 00:29,
  00:30 - 00:44,
  00:45: - 01:00
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/8Gena5MCW2H

I believe that's the functionality you are looking for but if not leave a comment.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$addFields: {
    // Add a numeric timestamp
    time: {
      $toLong: "$createdAt"
     }
  }},

  {$group: {
    _id: {
      // Divide by 15 sec and round down
      $floor: {
        $divide: [
          "$time",
          15000
        ]
      }
    },
    // Add the item count to the group output
    itemCount: {
      $sum: 1
    },
    // Add the item ids to an array (to help show the pipe works correctly)
    items: {
      $push: "$_id"
    }
  }},
  
  // Add a human readable date (again to help verify the pipe works)
  {$addFields: {
    date: {
      $convert: {
        input: {
          $multiply: [
            "$_id",
            15000
          ]
        },
        to: "date"
      }
    }
  }},

  {$sort: {
    date: 1
  }}

])
```

If you need to fill the data in between docs in the pipe you can use $accumulate. (Only available on 4.4)

Simply add the following stages:
Note: depends on sort asc in before

```
  {$group: {
    _id: null,
    docs: {
      $accumulator: {
        accumulateArgs: ["$$ROOT"],

        accumulate: function(state, group) {
          const lastGroup = state[state.length - 1];
          if (!lastGroup) {
            return [group];
          }

          // The amount of 'empty' spaces that need to be filled
          const needToFill = group._id - lastGroup._id - 1;

          const fillerContent = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < needToFill; i++) {
            // Current time block, subtract 1 to be at previous block
            // Subtract i to go back 1 block at a time
            // Multiply by 15000 sec to be a proper timestamp
            let fillingTimestamp = (group._id - 1 - i) * 15000;
            fillerContent.unshift({
              _id: fillingTimestamp,
              itemCount: 0,
              date: new Date(fillingTimestamp)
            })
          }

          return [...state, ...fillerContent, group]
        },
      
        init: function() {return []},
        merge: function(state1, state2) {return state1.concat(state2)},
        finalize: function(state) {return state},
        lang: "js"
      }
    }
  }},

  // Fix formatting
  {$unwind: '$docs'},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$docs'}}
```

If you're just outputting the result, then just use .reduce() so that we are not bloating the transport from the db.

(The exact same function using in accumulator)

```
res.reduce((state, group) => {
  const lastGroup = state[state.length - 1];
  if (!lastGroup) {
    return [group];
  }

  // The amount of 'empty' spaces that need to be filled
  const needToFill = group._id - lastGroup._id - 1;

  const fillerContent = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < needToFill; i++) {
    // Current time block, subtract 1 to be at previous block
    // Subtract i to go back 1 block at a time
    // Multiply by 15000 sec to be a proper timestamp
    let fillingTimestamp = (group._id - 1 - i) * 15000;
    fillerContent.unshift({
      _id: fillingTimestamp,
      itemCount: 0,
      date: new Date(fillingTimestamp)
    })
  }

  return [...state, ...fillerContent, group]
}, [])
```

Comment: is there any away to make appear the date and itemCount if the itemCount is 0

Comment: Yes. I updated the answer with a couple different options.